# multiThread process a log file ,how to keep the line order in the log file

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a question about the java concurrency .
Now i have a log file ,I want to use other threads to process the log file .each thread process a line (one record) in the file. at lat ,thest threads write the processed record to the same file .I want to know how to keep the record order with the origin log file ?

Comment: I wonder what you are doing to each line of each file to justify the overheads of doing it in multiple threads.

Comment: this is a common problem when you want to analysis your log file or make a download program. the multithread could improve the download speed and solve this question could ensure the download file is orderly ,not in a mess.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a mechanism to associate the line number with each record. Create a data structure to buffer the line written against correct index of record. And finally dump the file.

Comment: @amberzhang Im glad you are able to resolve your situation by using the recommendation and not seeking the code from anyone else:-) Proud of you, long way to go!

Comment: thanks , I have commit my code to the github ,https://github.com/amberlife/learnProcess/tree/master/src/NetWorkProgram/ch6 you can see my solution in the LookupThread.java ,PooledWeblog.java,Line.java .